# Change dateformat output

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am facing an annoying problem in my code.

I wanna have the output date look like this:

### 06/04/2014

```
document.getElementById("nights").value = diff + " nights"; {
    $('#arrival').datepicker().val();
    $('#departure').datepicker().val();
    var start = new Date(document.getElementById('arrival').value),
        end = new Date(document.getElementById('departure').value),
        currentDate = new Date(start),
        between = [];

    while (end > currentDate) {
        between.push(new Date(currentDate));
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    $('#lista').html(between.join('<br> '));
};
```

Where can I change the output format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` loop, try:

```
while (end > currentDate) {
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var year = currentDate.getUTCFullYear();
    between.push(month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

It looks like you are doing many more of these: `new Date(variable)` than necessary.

Comment: Btw, I set up the variables this way so you can add a `0` in front of single-digit months & days if you want.